# Getting error request for member 'indexPath' in something not a structure or union when compiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, ipod

I have an app made from tableview example, and I managed to get the files of documents directory listed on the table, and also got the way for seeing it's content on the detailview, now the problem comes when I edited one file and I want to save it. 
I get the error: request for member 'indexPath' in something not a structure or union when I want to access indexPath.row of the table view which is on RootViewController. This is the header for DetaiViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
@class RootViewController;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UITextView *labelName;
    NSString *strName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *labelName;

- (IBAction)saveText:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hideKeyb:(id)sender;
@end
```

And here is the IBOutlet in where I'm having trouble:

```
- (IBAction)saveText:(id)sender 
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *data = labelName.text;
    //RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [RootViewController alloc]
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt",rootViewController.indexPath.row+1];
    NSString *wheresave = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSData *aData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [aData writeToFile:wheresave atomically:YES];
}
```

The error is at `NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt",rootViewController.indexPath.row+1];`

I think I have all the imports ok, but i'm not sure :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're allocating RootViewController since it should be already allocated for what you're saying.

If you want to access a row (let's say that's the selected one, you can retrive any specific one if you want) in the RootViewController (assuming it's extending from UITableViewController) it should be something like this:

> NSIndexPath *indexPath =
> [rootViewController.tableView
> indexPathForSelectedRow];
>
> NSString
> *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt",indexPath.row+1];

Comment: Okay managed to compile, but it's not saving. I put an NSLog and it's not showing anything: NSLog(indexPath.row);